# postgresql and node time differs while executing query and displaying the result(want IST timezone but executing UTC timezone)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timestamp

i wanted to get the entries of this month records (in IST timezone) which is saved in postgresql as createdAt with type as timezone with timestamp.

this is my node js query to fetch current months records

```
firstday=dayjs().date(1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
lastday=dayjs().date(dayjs().daysInMonth()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');


Example.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [ { createdAt: { [Op.gte]: firstday } }, 
    { createdAt: { [Op.lte]: lastday } }, ]
  }
});
```

but while executing the query in node js i'm getting results for UTC timezone where the query is comparing with UTC time

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "createdAt" FROM "table1" AS "table1" WHERE ("table1"."createdAt" >= '2021-11-30 18:30:00.000 +00:00' AND "table1"."createdAt" <= '2021-12-31 18:30:00.000 +00:00');
```

but in postgresql the createdAt is stored as IST timezone

```
id |           createdAt
----+-------------------------------
  1 | 2021-12-12 19:12:14.602+05:30
  2 | 2021-12-12 19:13:29.942+05:30
```

i wanted the query to execute in IST timezone and gets the result based on IST timezone

Thanks

Comment: 1) If you are using `timestamp with time zone` for `createAT` then the values are being as `UTC`. You are seeing them as `IST` because the server `TimeZone` is set to `IST`. 2) In the JS where is the `date` function coming from? 3) What is the timezone setting for the client the JS script is running in? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: That should have been: 'If you are using timestamp with time zone for createAt then the values are being saved as UTC'. The point being Postgres does not save the input timezone.